# Почему ядро не полностью загружается?

Tags: c, ассемблер, fasm, ядро, загрузчик

Пытаюсь загрузить ядро, но оно не полностью загружается(?) затрудняюсь ответить что именно с ним происходит, ошибки не выдает, но не так работает, на команды не отвечает просто выводит, при нажатии энтора что ввела. Такое поведение появилось после того как ядро увеличилось в размере.

dumpbin когда ядро работало:

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    3FE1 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00011000 to 00014FE0)
    4000 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000043FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
    1046 virtual size
    5000 virtual address (00015000 to 00016045)
     200 size of raw data
    4400 file pointer to raw data (00004400 to 000045FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

SECTION HEADER #3
.data/IG name
    1E90 virtual size
    7000 virtual address (00017000 to 00018E8F)
    2000 size of raw data
    4600 file pointer to raw data (00004600 to 000065FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only
```

dumpbin, после того как добавила в ядро функцию, которая считает тики, после нее увеличилось само ядро и перестало корректно работать :

```
SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    4031 virtual size
    1000 virtual address (00011000 to 00015030)
    4200 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data (00000400 to 000045FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         Execute Read

SECTION HEADER #2
   .data name
    1046 virtual size
    6000 virtual address (00016000 to 00017045)
     200 size of raw data
    4600 file pointer to raw data (00004600 to 000047FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
C0000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Write

SECTION HEADER #3
.data/IG name
    1E90 virtual size
    8000 virtual address (00018000 to 00019E8F)
    2000 size of raw data
    4800 file pointer to raw data (00004800 to 000067FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only
```

загрузка ядра

```
use16
org 0x7C00
start:
mov ax, cs 
mov ds, ax  
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, start  

mov ax, cs 
mov ds, ax  
mov ss, ax 
mov sp, start 

mov ax, 0x1100
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1 
mov dh, 0 
mov ch, 0 
mov cl, 3
mov al, 33
mov ah, 0x02 
int 0x13

mov ax, 0x1600
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1
mov dh, 0
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 36
mov al, 1
mov ah, 0x02

int 0x13
mov ah, 0
mov al, 2
int 0x10

mov ax, 0x1800
mov es, ax
mov bx, 0x0000
mov dl, 1
mov dh, 0
mov ch, 0
mov cl, 37
mov al, 16
mov ah, 0x02
int 0x13 

  lgdt [gdt_info]
in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al    
mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp 0x8:protected_mode 
gdt:
db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
;base=0, size=4Gb, P=1, DPL=0, S=1(user),
;Type=1(code), Access=00A, G=1, B=32bit
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0xCF, 0x00
;base=0, size=4Gb, P=1, DPL=0, S=1(user),
;Type=0(data), Access=0W0, G=1, B=32bit
db 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x92, 0xCF, 0x00
gdt_info: 
dw gdt_info - gdt
dw gdt, 0
use32
protected_mode:
mov ax, 0x10
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
call 0x11000
times (512 - ($ - start) - 2) db 0 
db 0x55, 0xAA
```

функция которая считывает тики

```
__declspec(naked) void timer()
{
    __asm pusha;
    // Обработка поступивших данных
    ticks++;
    // Отправка контроллеру 8259 нотификации о том, что прерывание 
    /*обработано.Если не отправлять нотификацию, то контроллер не будет посылать
        новых сигналов о прерываниях до тех пор, пока ему не сообщать что
        прерывание обработано.*/
    outb(PIC1_PORT, 0x20);
    __asm {
        popa
        iretd
    }
}

void init_ticks(){
    intr_reg_handler(8, GDT_CS, 0x80 | IDT_TYPE_INTR, timer); // Регистрация обработчика прерывания (segm_sel=0x8, P=1, DPL=0, Type=Intr)
    outb(PIC1_PORT + 1, 0xFF ^ 0x01);
    }
```

Транслятор: FASM, ассемблер: Intel, компилятор: ms c

Comment: А ты пол какую платформу собираешь? x86, x86_64?

Comment: @ori под x86_64

Comment: ваш код только под х32 будет работать (если можно так выразиться), т.к. GDT 32-битная.

Comment: @PRODIGY, да когда я передаю управление в ядро, там есть строка .use32, код работал пока не увеличилось ядро в размере и я не знаю как теперь его загружать....

Comment: Если ядро получилось размером больше 512-байт (один сектор диска), то считывать через int-13h нужно уже 2 и более секторов. Во-вторых, чтобы обслуживать аппаратные прерывания таймера, в защищённом режиме помимо GDT нужна ещё и IDT (Interrupt Dispatch Table).

Comment: @PRODIGY "считывать через int-13h нужно уже 2 и более секторов" а можно поподробней, ибо у меня PE ядро инфы об этом почти нет

Comment: Ничё не понимаю.. В каком смысле у вас РЕ ядро? Это обычный *.exe чтоли? И что делало это ядро, пока вы не добавили в него таймер?

Comment: @PRODIGY "PE-файл kernel.bin, получаемый при компиляции кода ядра с 
помощью компилятора Microsoft, содержит несколько служебных 
заголовков" вот так написано в моей методичке, те PE-файл

Comment: Вы всё смешали в кучу. У файлов типа bin не может быть заголовка - это чистый бинарный код без примесей. Если-же говорится, что он имеет заголовки, то это РЕ с поддельным расширением. Для загрузки файлов этого типа в память, нужен специальный "загрузчик образов", который в Win числится как ImageLoader. Именно он читает заголовки Ре, и по ним распределяет части кода по секциям. Во-вторых, РЕ-файлы грузятся в виртуальную память, о создании которой вы не побеспокоились. Короче там много нюансов, а у вас на данный момент винегрет.

Comment: @PRODIGY о стало намного понятнее... как минимум, что читать) Спасибо! А может быть в теории, что ядро не загружается, потому что у ImageLoader мало выделено памяти для ядра? такое может быть?

Comment: ImageLoader - это системный сервис (демон в линухе). А у вас-же нет операционной системы, или есть? На данный момент, судя по вашему коду вы пытаетесь войти из RM в РМ (и то неправильно), и создали GDT с дескрипторами 4ГБ. Так-что памяти у вас предостаточно. Здесь больше никого нет, кроме железа, прерывания от которых вы должны обслуживать. В RM для этого биос уже создал таблицу IVT, но после входа в РМ она становится недействительна, и вместо неё нужно создавать IDT.

Comment: @PRODIGY да, но код взять полностью из методички, максимум что я в нем меняю это cl, ah, al  для загрузки ядра ;) (слеза)

Comment: что-то здесь не то.. Имеем загрузчик реального режима, и ядро в виде исполняемого РЕ-файла Windows. Это выглядит как минимум странно, т.к. сущности не совместимы между собой. Нужно посмотреть в методичке, что вы изучали до этого, и куда в данном контексте можно вообще пристроить бутлоадер.